# redisClient error Error: Socket closed unexpectedly

Tags: redis, haproxy

redis_version:7.2.4

HAProxy version 2.4.24

redis - docker containers

haproxy - package installation

---

I'm trying to use two redis servers with haproxy.
I don't get this error when I try to connect the redis servers separately, but when I connect them with haproxy, I get this error.

```
[2024-02-29T02:35:24.933] [ERROR] [localhost] [docId] [userId] nodeJS - redisClient error Error: Socket closed unexpectedly
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/snapshot/server/DocService/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:194:118)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
[2024-02-29T02:35:27.529] [ERROR] [localhost] [docId] [userId] nodeJS - [AMQP] conn error Error: Unexpected close
    at succeed (/snapshot/server/Common/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:272:13)
    at onOpenOk (/snapshot/server/Common/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:254:5)
    at /snapshot/server/Common/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:166:32
    at /snapshot/server/Common/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:160:12
    at Socket.recv (/snapshot/server/Common/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:499:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:578:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I don't know if this is a configuration issue with haproxy or if I need to do more work on redis.

[haproxy.cfg]

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        #option httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  10s
        timeout server  10s
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend redis_frontend
    bind *:6379  
    mode tcp
    default_backend redis_servers

backend redis_servers
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server redis1   192.168.0.207:6379 check
        server redis2   192.168.0.210:6379 check
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I read that you should try adjusting the timeout setting,
so I tried changing the timeout to 60s and then 10s.
Not surprisingly, this only changed the frequency of the error logs, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: "Error: Unexpected close" surely applies to the connection not the socket. Looks like Redis mangled this into "Socket closed unexpectedly". I would say your haproxy configuration isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `timeout client`, HAProxy disconnects inactive connections.Then you need a connection pool to periodically check idle connections, and the period should be less than `timeout client`.